# Facebook API missing fields on user profile

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am working on FB application using the PHP SDK. 
The implementation seems to be correct and everything seems fine.

The problem I am facing is that some users profiles do not contain an email address. That is wierd because the application asks for this permissions specifically.

Code for this action:

```
    // 1. If we cant get the user, log him in and request permissions if he has deleted/deauthorized or new to app
    if (!$fbCurrentUserID){
        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
            'scope' => 'email,user_birthday',
        ));
        $this->abortToUrl($loginUrl);
    }

    try {
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        if (!is_array($user_profile) || empty($user_profile['email'])) {
            if ($log = $this->getLog()) {
                $log->log('Facebook login no valid userprofile', Zend_Log::ALERT, array('user_profile' => $user_profile));
            }
            $this->abortToUrl($landingPage_url);
        }
        // 2.a User has provided data go on...
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        // 2.b Something bad happened. Worst case scenario so go to start
        if ($log = $this->getLog()) {
            $log->log($e->getMessage(), Zend_Log::CRIT);
        }
        // If he declined or anything went wrong go to LP
        $this->abortToUrl($landingPage_url);
    }
```

So I get quite a few logs with the user array not containing the email address field.

Am I missing something? I cannot reproduce this with test accounts or my account when I set email to be visible only to me.

Comment: Not every user has an email address set with FB, since you can also register using your mobile.

Comment: @CBroe Make it an answer and let's close this question. That was it. It was escaping my mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not every user has an email address set with FB, since you can also register using your mobile.